# any way to expand an Enum in Razor to simplify this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, enums

I have the following block of Javascript code that includes manually taking values and text of an enum, and placing them in to an Array called `source`:

```
$('#configuration').editable({ 
    url: '/UTS/UnitSave', 
    pk: '@Model.unit.c_number',
    prepend: "Unknown",
    source: [
    {
        value: @UnitStatus.Phases.Unknown,
        text: 'Unknown'
    },
    {
        value: @UnitStatus.Phases.Manufacturing,
        text: 'Manufacturing'
    },
    {
        value: @UnitStatus.Phases.Shipping,
        text: 'Shipping'
    },
    {
        value: @UnitStatus.Phases.Deployed,
        text: 'Deployed'
    }
    ]
});
```

This works OK, but if I were to add another value to `Phases`, I would need to remember to come back in to my `View` and modify the above block of code.  Is there any way to make this more robust and to simplify the code to expand the enum `UnitStatus.Phases`?

Answer (score 0):

We can't see here what *Phases* looks like, but if the are only what yo want to add to this *Object* in it, why not consider

```
function generatePhases(Phases) {
    var arr = [], key, has;
    has = Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty);
    for (key in Phases)
        if (has(Phases, key))
            arr.push({
                value: Phases[key],
                text: key
            });
    return arr;
}

// and usage
var o = { 
    url: '/UTS/UnitSave', 
    pk: '@Model.unit.c_number',
    prepend: "Unknown",
    source: generatePhases(@UnitStatus.Phases);
};
$('#configuration').editable(o);
```

---

The weird stuff with `bind`ing `call` to `hasOwnProperty` is to let you safely use `hasOwnProperty` without assuming that it is not shadowed on an *Object*.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your enum is a c# enum following is you could do.

```
namespace webapitest
{
    public enum UnitStatusPhases
        {
            Unknown,
            Manufacturing,
            Shipping,
            Deployed
        }

        public class utility
        {
           public static string SomeMethod(System.Type enumType)
            {
                List<MyEnumDescriptor> list = new List<MyEnumDescriptor>();

                foreach (Enum enumValue in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
                {
                    list.Add(new MyEnumDescriptor(enumValue.ToString(), enumValue.ToString()));
                }
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
            }

            class MyEnumDescriptor
            {
                public MyEnumDescriptor(string value, string text)
                {
                    this.Value = value;
                    this.Text = text;
                }
                public string Value { get; set; }
                public string Text { get; set; }
            }
        }
}
```

For json serialization i am using NewtonsoftJs

Than in your view you could write.

```
@using webapitest;
<div id="body">
    <section class="featured">
...
</section>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('just a alert');
    var value = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(utility.SomeMethod(typeof(UnitStatusPhases)))');
    console.log(value);
</script>
```

Hope that helps.